# How to retrieve data from related documents by ID?

Tags: mongodb, database-relations, database

I'm trying to understand how to set up basic relations in mongoDB. I've read a bit about it in the documentation but it's a little terse.

This should be pretty simple: I'm trying to log a list of impressions and the users who are responsible for the impressions. Here's some examples of log documents:

```
{type: '1', userId:'xxx-12345'}
{type: '1', userId:'xxx-12345'}
{type: '1', userId:'xxx-12345'}
{type: '2', userId:'zzz-84638'}
{type: '2', userId:'xxx-12345'}
```

Here's an example of a user document:

`{userId: 'xxx-12345', location: 'US'}`

Is there a way to count the total number of documents which "belong" to a `userId` of `xxx-12345`, where `type` is `1`?

In the above case, I'd want to see a result like `{ '1':3, '2':1 }`.

Also, is the above an acceptable way of creating the relationships?

Comment: You would like to count the impressions per type per userId? Or you would like to count the impressions per type for a given userid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st question `Is there a way to count the total number of documents which "belong" to a userId of xxx-12345, where type is 1?`, below is the solution:

```
db.impressions.aggregate({
                           $match: {
                                userId: 'xxx-12345',
                                type: 1
                           }
                         },
                         {
                              $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } }
                         });
```

To get the solution in format you specified (`In the above case, I'd want to see a result like { '1':3, '2':1 }.`), use below code:

```
db.impressions.aggregate({
                       $match: {
                            userId: 'xxx-12345',
                       }
                     },
                     {
                          $group: { _id: '$type', totalImpressions: { $sum: 1 } }
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) introduced in version 2.2:

```
db.a.aggregate([
  { $match: { userId: 'xxx-12345' } },
  { $group: { _id: "$type", total: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

This will output:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "2",
                        "total" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "1",
                        "total" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

where "_id" is the type and *"total"* is the count that type appears in user *"xxx-12345"*.

However, if you want to get only the *total number of documents which belong to "xxx-12345" where the type is "1"* you can do it like this:

```
db.a.aggregate([
  { $match: { userId: 'xxx-12345', type: "1" } },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1} } }
])
```

which will output the following:

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : null, "count" : 3 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

where "count" is what you're looking for.